# Testing promise with ava

Tags: node.js, testing, promise, nightmare, ava

I try to test this class

```
class Scraper {
  async run() {
    return await nightmare
      .goto(this.url)
      .wait('...')
      .evaluate(()=>{...})
      .end
  }
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
test('Scraper test', t => {
  new Scraper().run().then(() => {
    t.is('test', 'test')
  })
})
```

Test fails:

> Test finished without running any assertions

**EDIT**

repository on github: https://github.com/epyx25/test

test file: https://github.com/epyx25/test/blob/master/src/test/scraper/testScraper.test.js#L12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to return the promise. Assertion planning is not needed:

```
test('Scraper test', t => {
  return new Scraper().run().then(() => {
    t.is('test', 'test')
  })
})
```

Or better still, using an async test:

```
test('Scraper test', async t => {
  await new Scraper().run()
  t.is('test', 'test')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you must using [assert-planning](https://github.com/avajs/ava#assertion-planning) to blocking the test until the lambda is notified by the `Promise`, for example:

```
test('Scraper test', t => {
   t.plan(1);
   return new Scraper().run().then(() => {
     t.is('test', 'test')
   })
})
```

**OR**

```
test.cb('Scraper test', t => {
   t.plan(1);
   new Scraper().run().then(() => {
     t.is('test', 'test')
     t.end()
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I does not work. Here is what I get: Rejected promise returned by test

  Rejection reason:

    "cov_1fanynun32 is not defined" When I run my app. the method works fine. Only in the test gets rejected.

Comment: `cov_1fanynun32 is not defined` would come from a code coverage tool that's being used incorrectly. This is not due to AVA, returning the promise is fine.

Comment: @MarkWubben googling `cov_1fanynun32` does not return anything. I cloned this skeleton project: https://github.com/Skahrz/project-skeleton. here is the repo on github: https://github.com/epyx25/test

Comment: @user3568719 well. there is an example likes as mine just for you. https://github.com/epyx25/test/blob/master/src/test/scraper/testScraper.test.js#L12-L19

Comment: @holi-java yes, that test was written by me, but it has the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: @user3568719 I'll try it later. :)

Comment: @MarkWubben thanks for the tip! removing ˙nyc` from `"test": "nyc ./node_modules/.bin/ava",` solves the problem! How did you know, that the code coverage (in this case nyc) is the problem? What could be the solution?

Comment: @user3568719 just recognized the variable. Pretty sure it shouldn't crash like that though.